# Core Plot: Pan and zoom two plot spaces along x-axis and auto-scaling both y-axes

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, core-plot

I have a Core Plot chart with two line plots (plot 1 uses the `y`-axis on the LHS, plot 2 uses the `y2`-axis on the RHS) and two plot spaces (`lhsPlotSpace` and `rhsPlotSpace`).

For the initial plot set-up, I use `scaleToFitPlots`to autoscale the two plots, which works as expected:

```
[lhsPlotSpace scaleToFitPlots:lhsPlots];
[rhsPlotSpace scaleToFitPlots:rhsPlots];
```

The plot then looks similar to the screen shot below.

In order to show more details, I would like to allow the user to pan horizontally and to zoom horizontally as long there is more data to be shown on the left and right (panning and zooming should be user driven only along the `x`-axis).

The `y`-axis and `y2`-axis should be scaled automatically depending on the range visible after panning and zooming.

Could you please help me a bit with this problem? I tried to use the delegate

Based on the code example I have found in the Core Plot forums and on StackOverFlow I tried to do this using the delegate method `plotSpace:willChangePlotRangeTo:forCoordinate`

```
- (CPTPlotRange *)plotSpace:(CPTPlotSpace *)space 
willChangePlotRangeTo:(CPTPlotRange *)newRange 
forCoordinate:(CPTCoordinate)coordinate
{
if (coordinate == CPTCoordinateY) {
   newRange = ((CPTXYPlotSpace*)space).yRange;

return newRange     
}
```

but besides getting very basic zooming, I did not found a solution which is even close to my problem.

Could you please point me to which delegates methods to use, how to restrict scrolling and how and where to set the new `y`-scale factor after panning and zooming?

Thank you very much!

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Set the `globalYRange` of each plot space to the corresponding `yRange` to prevent scaling and scrolling in the y-direction.

`-scaleToFitPlots:` uses all plot data for the given plots when computing the new ranges. If you want to scale the plot space `yRange` based on the visible data, you'll have to do that yourself in the plot space delegate. The `-plotSpace:willChangePlotRangeTo:forCoordinate:` delegate method is a good choice for this.